# Why this algorithm takes O(nlgn) time?

Tags: algorithm

In the , Chapter 5, 5.3 Randomized algorithms,

```
   PERMUTE-BY-SORTING(A)
n = A.length
let P[1..n] be a new array
for i = 1 to n
P[i] = RANDOM(1, n^3)
sort A, using P as sort keys
```

Why the algorithm PERMUTE-BY-SORTING takes O(nlgn) time, please?

Comment: Seems like something you could quite easily google...

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple.

1. `n = A.length` takes O(1)
2. `let P[1..n] be a new array` creation of a new array of length n takes `O(n)`
3. `for i = 1 to n {P[i] = RANDOM(1, n^3)}` n times you assign a random number from 1 to n^3. Getting a random number is `O(1)` so in total `O(n)`
4. `sort A, using P as sort keys` takes `O(nlogn)`

Summing all up you get: `O(1) + O(n) + O(n) + O(nlogn)` which is `O(nlogn)`